# $I_T(H)$ and $\mathbb E[I(H)^3]$ for $H(t)=W(1)I_{[1,2)}(t)+W(2)I_{[3,4)}(t), t\ge 0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let

$$H(t)=W(1)I_{[1,2)}(t)+W(2)I_{[3,4)}(t), t\ge 0$$

($I$ describes the indicator function and $W(t)$ is Brownian motion)

> How can I calculate $I_T(H)=\int_{0}^{T}H(t)dW(t)$ for $T>0$ and $\mathbb E[I(H)^3]$?

$I(H):=\int_{0}^{\infty}H(t)dW(t)$.

I know how to calculate $\mathbb E[I(H)^2]$ if that helps.

$T\ge 4$:

$I_T(H)=I(H)=W_1(W_2-W_1)+W_2(W_4-W_3)$

$T \in [3,4)$:

$I_T(H)=W_1(W_2-W_1)+W_2(W_T-W_3)$

$T \in [2,3)$:

$I_T(H)=W_1(W_2-W_1)$

$T \in [1,2)$:

$I_T(H)=W_1(W_T-W_1)$

$T < 1$:

$I_T(H)=0$

Comment: Use exactly the same idea as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3258877/36150)

Comment: @saz So this leaves me with the terms $\mathbb E \int_{1}^{2}W(1)^3$ and $\mathbb E \int_{3}^{4}W(2)^3$ but I can't simply interchange the order of $\mathbb E$ and $\int$ as in the question you linked using fubini. So how do I continue? And I still don't know how to determine $I_T(H)$. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use Fubini? Sure you can.

Comment: @saz I'm wondering if the integrand can become negative? In the case $(.)^2$ it's non-negative so there are no problems.

Comment: $W(t)$ is Gaussian, right? In particular we have nice bounds for moments of arbitrary order. Using e.g. that $W_t$ equals in distribution $\sqrt{t} W_1$ we get $\mathbb{E}(|W_t|^k) = t^{k/2} \mathbb{E}(|W_1|^k)$. As $\mathbb{E}(|W_1|^k)< \infty$ (since $W_1$ is Gaussian) this gives a suitable bounds which allows to apply Fubini.

Comment: @saz Okay thanks a lot. How can I compute $I_T(H)$? I know that $I(H)=W_1(W_2-W_1)+W_2(W_4-W_3)$. I guess if have to look at different cases for example $T \in [1,2)$ but I don't know

Comment: @saz I added my try above. I would appreciate it if you can have a look at it

Comment: It's correct what you have done.